# Почему при получении конструктора класса возвращается null?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Почему при получении конструктора класса возвращается `null`

```
class myClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public myClass()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Type t = typeof(myClass).GetType();
    ConstructorInfo constr = t.GetConstructor(new[] { t });
}
```

Но при обращении к `GetConstructors` всё возвращается нормально.

Comment: потому что в классе `myClass` нет конструктора, который принимает параметром объект класса `myClass`

Comment: class myClass
        {
            public int a { get; set; }
            public int b { get; set; }
            public myClass(int a)
            {
                a = 2;
                b = 2;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Type t = typeof(myClass).GetType();
            ConstructorInfo constr = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
        }

Comment: переделаем, чтобы принимал инт и будем искать по инту...но результат тот же @Grundy

Comment: Что значит код в комментарии?

Comment: @Grundy я изменил, чтобы конструктор принимал int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var type = typeof(myClass);
var constructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
```

**Получение типа**

Для получения типа на этапе компиляции достаточно использования оператора `typeof`. Оператор `typeof` принимает в качестве параметра имя типа. Для получения типа во время выполнения - метода `Object.GetType()`, который возвращает `Type` для существующего объекта:

```
var myClassInstance = new myClass();
var type = myClassInstance.GetType();
```

Совместное их использование не имеет смысла.

**Получение конструктора без параметров**

Метод `Type.GetConstructor(Type[])` ищет конструктор, параметры которого соответствуют типам, содержащимся в переданном в метод массиве. Так как требуется найти конструктор без параметров, следует использовать значение поля `Type.EmptyTypes`.

Comment: Постарайся писать более развернутые ответы

Comment: стоит добавить что `typeof` - применяется к типам, а `GetType` к объектам.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нет конструктора с параметром, надо передавать Type.EmptyTypes [Метод Type.GetConstructor (Type[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx). И не понятно, зачем вы берёте тип у типа typeof(myClass).GetType()?

```
class myClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public myClass()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var constr = typeof(myClass).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
}
```